# ElementHost not refreshing after workbook moved over it in Excel 2010

Tags: wpf, excel, c#-4.0, vsto, excel-2010

I have wierd issue with ElementHost on CustomTaskPane in Excel 2010 32bit on Windows 7 x64, .NET 4.0

Control inside Host (or host itself) is not repainted after workbook window was moved around.
To illustrate this I have created sample:

```
    _host = new ElementHost { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, BackColorTransparent = false, BackColor = Color.Blue };
    _userControl = new UserControl();
    _userControl.Controls.Add(_host);
    _taskPane = CustomTaskPanes.Add(_userControl, "Pane");
    _taskPane.Visible = true;
```

I've omitted child control for simplicity, as result is the same.

Here is how it looks as expected:
[image]

Now I moved workbook around a bit, and I get:
[image]

Obviously grey and black areas are not expected (same result with actual control hosted). _host refresh fixes the issue -- repaints itself and child, but problem is I didnt find any event in VSTO to detect when workbook was moved.

Questions:

1. Where do those black/grey areas come from?
2. Is it possible to avoid/fix it and how?
3. (as a workaround) Is it possible to detect workbook window movement so I can refresh _host and pray its the only scenario it happens? (bad idea)

Other tests shows that windows forms controls doesn't suffer from this behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a true XAML user control into the ElementHost.

In your WPF user control, make a grid with background color = blue.

Don't rely on element host itself

Also check updates, elementHost in VSTO gets lot of bugs.

Comment: I've omitted child control for simplicity, as result is the same